# Are there rules for how far sound travels?

Tags: dnd-5e

What are the rules for how far sound can travel in 5E?

The only rule I can find is the DMG description on page 105:

> ### Sounds
>
> A dungeon's enclosed geography helps channel sound. The groaning creak of an opening door can echo down hundreds of feet of passageway. Louder noises such as the clanging hammers of a forge or the din of battle can reverberate through an entire dungeon. Many creatures that live underground use such sounds as a way of locating prey, or go on alert at any sound of an adventuring party's intrusion.

Comment: @nitsua60 I don't think it's a duplicate, but it sure is related. That one refers to just those toys, this one asks for the rules of sound propagation in general.

Comment: I'd argue that this is asking for the general rule and the Clockwork Toy question is a specific case/instance of this question.  The answer on "Clockwork Toy" answers the general question quite well.  May the Mods can find a nice way to merge?

Comment: @Escoce I agree the *question* isn't a strict duplicate, but I thought the answer there answered this, as well. I was under the impression that that creates a reason for merger. Otherwise I'd just copy-paste that answer here, which doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Closing as duplicate provides a pointer to the other question.  Merging is only for when there's valuable answers on both we want to combine; there aren't any here.

Comment: The only argument I can see for merging is if we want *this* to be the canonical question; then we would move those answers here and mark the older question as a dup of this one instead of the other way around.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie well that's what I was thinking, that this question should supercede the other question. The other one about toys would be a subset of this question, OR this question would be the superset of that one. It makes no sense to link this overarching rules question to that one which asks for the answer to a specific set of circumstances.

Comment: Is this question general, or specific?  Since a few spells do specify a range at which a sound can be heard,  what is it that's being asked?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast its general. The situation that came up was how far away is too far to use a perception check to hear someone.